# Android - How to Convert String to utf-8 in android

Tags: java, android, utf-8, encode

I can't convert a String to UTF-8 in android. please help me!!

```
s1=URLEncoder.encode("臺北市")
```

result : `%EF%BF%BDO%EF%BF%BD_%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD`

But "`臺北市`" should be encoded as "`%E8%87%BA%E5%8C%97%E5%B8%82`"

Comment: I use  URLEncoder.encode("臺北市", "utf-8"),but not yet solution .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html you can read that the you used is deprecated and that you should use `static String encode(String s, String charsetName)`

So `URLEncoder.encode("臺北市", "utf-8")` should do the trick.

Comment: The result still be %EF%BF%BDO%EF%BF%BD_%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD

Comment: `%EF%BF%BDO%EF%BF%BD_%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD` is not a UTF-8 encoded sequence.

Comment: But "URLEncoder.encode("臺北市", "utf-8")" output is %EF%BF%BDO%EF%BF%BD_%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD

Comment: If that is true, than Android's implementation is broken and should be reported to Google. In the meantime, url encoding is easy to implement manually. Use `"臺北市".getBytes("utf-8")` and then convert each non-ASCII-alphanumeric byte to its `"%XX"` hex representation.

Answer (score 17):

```
public class StringFormatter {

    // convert UTF-8 to internal Java String format
    public static String convertUTF8ToString(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

    // convert internal Java String format to UTF-8
    public static String convertStringToUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```

You can convert your string using StringFormatter class to your code.

You want to convert to UTF-8:

```
String normal="This normal string".
String utf=StringFormatter.convertStringToUTF8(normal);
```

You want to convert UTF-8 to normal format:

```
String normal=StringFormatter.convertUTF8ToString(normal);
```

Comment: Add some description about what you wrote above.

Comment: It's using default encoding to convert string to UTF-8.

Answer (score 8):

You can just use,

```
URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

This will encode your "string: in UTF-8 format.

Put it in a try/catch and check for IllegalArgumentException if you want to. And if you have any spaces in your string, please replace it with

```
string.replace(" ", "%20");
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? Please accept the answer if it helped you. It is the way of saying "thank you" in SO.

Comment: Extraordinary answer. specially the `string.replace(" ", "%20");` part. this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
        URLEncoder.encode("臺北市", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Your second example is encoding a String into bytes using Java's default encoding (which is not guaranteed to be UTF-8) and is then creating a new String interpreting the bytes as if they were UTF-8.  That is not even close to what `URLEncoder.encode()` does (although your first example is correct for the question asked).