# Hindi/Non-English Words Not Displaying Properly, Used String as Datatype

Tags: android

I'm trying to fetch data from a web server using Volley. Everything works fine but when data contains non-English words, those aren't showing properly. I've been using String as Datatype:

```
String title;
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
title = object.getString("title");
```

Here's title in JSON output: केले की कार चोर निर्माता Banana Car Comedy Video हिंदी कहानियां Hindi Kahaniya Funny Comedy Video

Here's the output of Title in the layout:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the HTTP connection and all code files use UTF-8 encoding. The one duplicate I've linked shows how to handle the UTF-8 response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109345/android-how-to-convert-string-to-utf-8-in-android